# Reverse a linked list after a given value, without creating new nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm really stuck with that exercise. I can reverse a linked list with no problem, but I don't know how to do it without creating new nodes.

Implement a function reverse() to reverse the elements in a linked list
from the first occurrence of a given value. 
e.g. given the input A B C D E F and the value D return the list A B C F E D

You should do this inplace without creating new nodes.

```
struct Node
{
    struct Node* next;
    int val;
};

void reverse( struct Node* head, int val);
```

Could you give me some tips?

This is what I have right now :

```
struct Node
{
    struct Node* next;
    int val;
};

void reverse(struct Node* head)
{
   struct Node *p = head,
                *q = NULL,
                *r;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        r = q;
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
        q->next = r;
    }
    q = head;
}

void reverseAfter( struct Node* head, int val )
{
    while(head)
    {
        if(head->val == val)
            reverse(head);
        else
            head = head->next;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: why val being passed as arg in reverse method?

Comment: It can not be in reverse order from the first element (given value A).

Comment: @iharob I have edited the question with my current program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void reverse(Node **head){
    Node *tmp, *list, *newList = NULL;
    if (head==NULL || *head == NULL) return;
    list = *head;
    while(list != NULL){
        tmp = list;
        list = list->next;
        tmp->next = newList;
        newList = tmp;
    }
    *head = newList;
}

void print(Node *head){
    while(head){
        printf("%d ", head->val);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void reverseAfter(Node *head, int val){
    //The first element excluded
    if(head == NULL) return ;

    while(head->next && head->next->val != val)
        head = head->next;
    reverse(&head->next);
}

int main(void){
    Node *head;
    Node n[6] = {
        {1,NULL}, {2, NULL}, {3, NULL},
        {4,NULL}, {5, NULL}, {6, NULL}
    };
    n[0].next = &n[1];n[1].next = &n[2];n[2].next = &n[3];
    n[3].next = &n[4];n[4].next = &n[5];

    head = &n[0];
    print(head);//1 2 3 4 5 6
    //reverse(&head);
    reverseAfter(head, 4);
    print(head);//1 2 3 6 5 4
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple single-linked list like yours can be seen as a stack. Reversing a stack is very simple: Pop the first node from the current stack, push onto a new stack. And again, and again until the first stack is empty.

Comment: wouldn't that create new node in the process?

Comment: @Neva Not if by "popping" the stack just unlinks the top-node and you reuse the node for the new stack.